# Make AUCTeX compile each \include to a separate file

Tags: latex, auctex

In `LaTeX` it is customary to put the content of different chapters into different files which are then pulled into a *master* file using `\include{FILENAME}` statements. One can then use the `\includeonly{SPEC}` command to compile only those chapters which are specified by `SPEC`.

The TeX.SO question [`Typeset single chapter from book`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8400/typeset-single-chapter-from-book) shows how to do this. Here comes my question:

> Is it possible to tell `AUCTeX` to parse through the master file and compile each of the `\include`'d files to its own pdf file?

Say I have this:

```tex
\documentclass{book}

\begin{document}
\include{Chap1}
\include{Chap2}
\include{Chap3}
\end{document}
```

in a file called `Master.tex`. The function I'm looking for would then compile `Chap1` to `Master_Chap1.pdf`, `Chap2` to `Master_Chap2.pdf` and so on [By using `\includeonly` I'd assume].

Comment: AUCTeX does not provide any command for this purpose.  You'll need to write your own.  I fail to see a use case for this, though. Why do you want separate files per chapter, rather than just one PDF, if you're processing all chapters anyway?

Comment: This is would be a very useful feature during the proofreading process.

Comment: I can't see how proof-reading was eased by having the document split into per-chapter PDFs?  You could just as well read through the entire PDF.

Comment: Unless you send different chapters to different reviewers or at different stages of the proofreading process.

Comment: Also, my previous search has shown [I am not the only one](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/auctex/2010-04/msg00038.html) who thinks something like this would be useful.

Comment: LaTeX can parse its files better than any custom elisp. So you should look for a LaTeX package IMO. The `subfiles` LaTeX package should do what you are looking for.

Answer (score 3):

**EDIT:** Totally didn't read all the comments on the answer. Looks like the `subfiles` LaTeX package might be a cleaner way. Leaving this here because options.

There is not a built-in way to do this. After a bit of elisp hacking, I came up with this solution:

```
(defun TeX-compile-all-chapters-from-master (cmd prefix)
  "Compile chapters using `CMD' with prefix `PREFIX'.

Each \include{foo} will be processed by running `CMD' formatted with args `PREFIX', `NAME' (foo in this example) and `TMP-FILE-NAME'."
  (let ((text (buffer-string)))
    (save-excursion
      (goto-char 0)
      (while (search-forward-regexp "\\(include\\){\\(.+\\)}" (buffer-size) t)
        (let* ((name (match-string 2))
               (tmp-file-name (concat "/tmp/tex-compile-all-" name))
               (incl-end (match-end 1)))
          (with-temp-file tmp-file-name
            (insert text)
            (goto-char incl-end)
            (insert "only"))
          (TeX-run-compile nil (format cmd prefix name tmp-file-name) nil)
          (delete-file tmp-file-name))))))
```

Example usage:

```
(TeX-compile-all-chapters-from-master "pdflatex -jobname %s_%s %s" "Master")
```

To bind this to a key, use `define-key` and either a `lambda` containing the above or `apply-partially`.
*Note to ELispers:* Fairly sure my code isn't idiomatic in several areas (`(insert text)`, tmp file name generation). Please help.